# Wrong "this" when calling a superclass method from a callback in a subclass in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've got some TypeScript code that (effectively) looks like this:

```
class User {
    name: string = "Bob";
    sayHello(): void {
        console.log("Hello, " + this.name);
    }
}

class RegisteredUser extends User {
    name: string = "Frank";
    sayHello(): void {
        var s = super;
        setTimeout(() => s.sayHello(), 1000);
    }
}

var registeredUser = new RegisteredUser();
registeredUser.sayHello();
```

The problem is that TypeScript (inexplicably, IMO) follows the weird JavaScript rules about "this" instead of doing it how every other programming language in the world does it. And so when User.sayHello() is called from the override in RegisteredUser.sayHello(), the `this` points to the User *class* rather than to the instantiated RegisteredUser *object*, so that what is actually logged is:

```
Hello, undefined
```

Beyond the fact that this doesn't make any sense to me to do it this way (see https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/477), what's the best way to work around this, so that `this` in User.sayHello() is pointing to the right object when called from a callback?

Comment: typescript follows the rules of javascript because it IS javascript.

Comment: But it isn't, at least, not when it's dealing with classes. In a class, there should be a keyword - if not `this` then `me` or `that` or something - that is absolutely, period, bound to the class. How often do people take advantage of how `this` is implemented in JS vs. how often are they forced to work around it? I can understand the JS rules when it comes to loose functions (`this` doesn't have a class to be bound to, so if you're gonna have the keyword at all, it has to be bound to the function's owner). But when it comes to classes, the rules need to be different.

Comment: Well, look at it from the porting from javascript to typescript angle. If I take a large pure javascript app now and drop it into typescript, I can change module definitions to use the class keyword and everything will still work. I can then methodically rip out "that = this" hacks and replace them with arrow syntax/lambdas and it will work, and the conversion process was explicit. If dropping in the class keyword totally broke everything else, then it's a process of debugging instead of regimented porting. I dunno. I agree with you academically, but the pragmatist in me is unsure.

Comment: @x0n - Good point about the porting bit. What do you think about my idea of a separate keyword (`me`?), only available inside classes, which should always point to the class instance, regardless of whether you're calling it with `function()` or lambdas or where it elsewhere gets assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works and gets rid of the need for the `s` var:

```
sayHello(): void {
    setTimeout(super.sayHello.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: But aren't you actually calling `this.sayHello` again since the *context* is `this` and not `super`?

Comment: @Cody No, it's explicitly telling `setTimeout` to call `super.sayHello` (the base class version) but to pass the current `this` as the context.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this works:

```
setTimeout(() => s.sayHello.call(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid the `var s = super` assignment, and call `super.sayHello` directly, TS will insert that magic incantation for you. Try it in the TS Playground.

Comment: I specifically tried that, and it won't let me. The compiler gives me the error, "The keyword `super` can only be used inside a class instance method." Of course, I think that's a mistake in the language - TS needs to look more like C#, IMO, and less like JS - but I'm not sure Anders Hejlsberg agrees with me :-).

Comment: You're quite right, I missed the error hint in the Playground. `.call` or `.bind` is the ES5 solution, but there should be a nicer approach. Sounds like a topic for es-discuss (my email about it seems stuck in some filter atm).

Comment: Feedback on es-discuss, from ES6 spec editor: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-December/026793.html

Comment: Thanks, @claus! For what it's worth, I really think that issues related to `this` are one of the biggest problems in JS at the moment. It seems like coders take advantage of the defined behavior of `this` much less often than they are forced to work around it. It would be awesome if ES6 could fix that, at least for classes. Perhaps even a separate keyword (`me`? `that`?) which, inside classes, is *always* bound to the class, regardless of whether the function gets assigned somewhere else or not.